# Getting intent filter category string from Android manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Hi All This should be simple but I can't find any info on this...

I simply want to read the intent category in the android manifest...

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="This" />
        </intent-filter>
```

i am able to get `VersionName & PackageName` but unable to get Category.

Comment: are you talking about this? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html

Comment: i want to fetch this string in onCreate.

Comment: intent.getAction() gives you the action i know this but intent.getCategories() gives what. i do not know. try this and Let me know.

Comment: vivek thanks yaar , but i am working in a project where i have to categorize apps according to its category , like all browsers together.

Comment: is it useful?. intent.getCategories() giving what you want.?

Comment: Are you trying to read this info using the `PackageManager`? If so, that isn't possible.

Comment: this cant be done , from code .